# Having issues on a validation for email on a table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

What i'm trying to do is to validate the email of a certain register on a trigger. For example if a customer is registered for the first time it should create an email with both first and last name **(example: user.last@email.com)** however if there's already a register with the same name it should create the email the same way with the first and last name following the customer_id **(example: user.last2@email.com)**.

The code that i have so far is the following:

```
delimiter $
create trigger before_customer_insert
before insert on customer
for each row
begin
 declare emailVal varchar(45);
 declare checkData int;
 declare checkData2 int;

 set checkData = (select count(first_name) from customer where first_name = new.first_name);
 set checkData2 = (select count(last_name) from customer where last_name = new.last_name);
 if((checkData = 1) and (checkData2 = 1)) then
    set new.email = (concat(new.first_name,'.', new.last_name, '@sakilacustomer.org'));
 else
    set new.email = (concat(new.first_name,'.', new.last_name, new.customer_id, '@sakilacustomer.oeg'));
 end if;

 if(new.kind_customer is null) then
    set new.kind_customer = '1';
 end if;

 set new.active = 1;
 end $
```

The problem that i'm having is that when it's the first register it inserts the email but with a 0 for example "name.last0@email.com" and if i try and insert with the same information shows the same email. I tried to change the logic in the if statements but still showed the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is backward. You have:

```
if((checkData = 1) and (checkData2 = 1)) then
```

But you want:

```
if((checkData = 0) and (checkData2 = 0)) then
```

You want to use the name without a customer ID when there AREN'T any existing records in the database with those names.

Note I'm not sure your check of looking for first names and last names separately is quite what you want. Wouldn't you want to check if the whole address is found as-is?

The way it's written, if someone named Joe Bloggs tries to join, he'll be joe.bloggs1 if there's anybody else named Joe in the system, even if there is no other Joe Bloggs.